# Dynamic field for Laravel Nova resources

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

In order to let users enter dynamic content in Nova resources, I need to figure out how to make make a field dynamic in Laravel Nova? Users should be able to select the type of the field (from the available [nova fileds](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/fields.html#field-types)) and enter the value respectively on the creation/update forms (example: if the chosen field is "Boolean Field", then show the toggle field). I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

The way I've solved this in the past is to have a model called `Field`. Each `Field` has a `label`, `key`, `type`, and `options` (if it is a Select or BooleanGroup).

I usually use a `Textarea` and tell people to put each option on its own line, and explode it by `PHP_EOL` to get it in an array.

Then in the model I need dynamic fields for, I have a `longText` column which casts to `array` via the model `$casts` property. I usually just call this `fields`.

In the Nova resource, I make a Panel and iterate through the `Field` models. I return the relevant Nova field based on the field `type`. When declaring the dynamic fields, I use the field `label` and `key` like this:

```php
public function fields()
{
    return [
        Panel::make('Dynamic Fields', $this->dynamicFields());
    ];
}

public function dynamicFields()
{
    $fields = Field::all();
    $dynamicFields = [];

    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if ($field->type == 'Boolean Group') {
            $dynamicFields[] = BooleanGroup::make($field->label, "fields->{$field->key}")
                ->options(array_combine($options = explode(PHP_EOL, $field->options), $options));
        }
    }

    return $dynamicFields;
}
```

Hope this gives you a bit of an idea of how to accomplish this.